# Ansible - 'unicode object' has no attribute 'file_input'

Tags: unicode, nested, ansible

I'm working with Ansible 2.2.1.0 and I work on a old project made by someone else with errors.

I have the following variables in my code:

```
software_output:
   - { file_input: 'Download_me.zip', file_output: 'download.zip' }

software_version:"0.5,0.6"
```

And I have this shell module instruction to download on a FTP:

```
- name: "MySoftware | get package on FTP"
  shell: >
    curl --ftp-ssl -k {{ ' --ssl-allow-beast ' if os == 'aix' else "" }} -# -f -u {{ ftp_user }}:{{ ftp_password }} -f "{{ ftp_url | replace('@@software_version@@',item[1]) }}{{ item[0].file_input }}"
    -o {{ require_inst_dir }}/{{ item[0].file_output }} 2>/dev/null
  with_nested:
    - software_output
    - "{{ software_version.split(',') }}"
  when: software_version is defined
```

But it doesn't work at all, I have the following error:

```
'unicode object' has no attribute 'file_input'
```

It looks like with_nested is not used as it has to be used, did I missed something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In:

```
with_nested:
  - software_output
```

`software_output` is a string `software_output`.

To refer to the variable value, change to:

```
with_nested:
  - "{{ software_output }}"
```

---

<sup>Long time ago the first syntax was valid, but it was long time ago.</sup>

Comment: Oh you are right Techraf ! how could I missed that ?
Probably because a big part of our projects are always based on very old Ansible version.

Thank you very much !